# How to retrieve form data with react-hook-form in antd table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, antd, react-hook-form

I am using controller in `react-hook-form` in a separate component like this

```
<Controller
  control={control}
  defaultValue={defaultValue}
  name={name}
  render={({ field: { onChange, value } }) => (
    <Input onChange={onChange} value={value} />
  )}
/>
```

Now I am implementing it like this to edit rows in an antd table like this

```
 const columns = [
    {
      key: "name",
      title: "Name",
      dataIndex: "name",
      width: "30%",
      sorter: (a: Record, b: Record) =>
        compareStringsABC(a.name || "", b.name || ""),
      sortDirections: ["descend", "ascend"],
      render: (text: string, record: SummaryRecord) => {
        if (editingRow === record.key) {
          return (
            <Controller control={control} defaultValue={text} name="name" />
          );
        } else {
          return <p>{text}</p>;
        }
      }
    },
```

I have a problem with where to add `handleSubmit` so i can retrieve modified data.

I m using `antdV3` (can't change to another version at the moment cos it requires alot of updates)

When I wrap the `<Form><Table /></Form>` I get an error that i am wraping a form with another form.
What is the best way to fix this?